# What maintenance can I perform on my GROHE 33 755 KD0 Ladylux Cafe Pull-Out kitchen faucet?

Tags: faucet, maintenance

We moved into our house shortly after the previous owners installed this [faucet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0012Q59QG):

[image: Picture of Grohe 33755 KDO faucet]

We've had it for about 5 years now and the water flow is severely limited.  Also, it takes forever for the hot water, but when I remove the faucet head it seems normal.  I was just going to replace the faucet head, but a new one is $200.  There's no instructions or documentation for the faucet, so I don't know if I'm supposed to be cleaning out the faucet head.

Can somebody either advise what I can do, or tell me where I can find some documentation online?  I checked Grohe's site but I can't find this specific model.

Comment: Many high end faucets like these have a lifetime warranty. Does yours? Did you call customer service?

Comment: Only 5 year warranty, and they require proof of purchase date which we do not have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing, disassembling (take notes!), and soaking the faucet head in a mix of hot water and **vinegar** (50/50) for a short while (e.g. an hour or two), to help remove any tap water mineral deposits that may have made their way into the head of your faucet and that are restricting your water flow.

Faucet heads typically have very fine passages and/or aerator mesh, and it's not uncommon for a build-up of tap water mineral deposits to cause water flow problem over time.  I've experienced this first hand, and a good vinegar soak did the trick.

Best of luck.

Comment: It's the disassembling of the faucet head that I'm struggling with.  I can't figure out how to do it!

Comment: @MikeC Aha, I see.  Even if you can't disassemble it, give it a good soak, perhaps for longer (overnight?), and repeat if necessary.  Shake it around in the vinegar container to make sure the solution gets into the right places.  If you're lucky, the vinegar may de-mineralize the head sufficiently so that the next time you run water through it, the small pieces of gunk get washed out.

Comment: I have them soaking now.  I'm trying to disassemble the head as much as possible.

Comment: This did the trick!  I've soaked it before, but opening it up really got the gunk out.

Comment: @MikeC Great- glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

Our Ladylux café with the pullout spray exhibited the low pressure issue a few weeks ago. I ended up unscrewing the head from the metal hose and cleaning out the filter and flow rate limiter.

Then, I dug through the cabinet to find the mysterious black plastic tool that came with the faucet and used it to unscrew the business end of the spray head. I cleaned out the screen in there, reassembled and reattached the head to the hose and I'm back to full pressure.

[image: Spray head exploded view. Arrows indicate parts to clean.]

Comment: Where is the business end?  And what is G is that the plastic tool?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the [specifications](http://www.grohecatalog.com/product/33755) page for your faucet.  And here's the [installation instructions](http://www.groheamerica.com/lib/1/tpi/1120374.pdf) for the 33758 model, which looks very similar to yours, enough that the maintenance instructions might be the same.

**EDIT:** I found the [installation instructions](http://docs.homeclick.com/PE-Links/Grohe/Grohe-33755-manual.pdf) for the 33755.

Comment: Thanks, this led me to learning that the spray end of the faucet head could be removed.  Still poking around, but I think I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I had a loss of pressure problem with mine and I took the spray head off - just twisted it off from the hose.
Soaked the spray head overnight in vinegar/water solution.  It helped but it still wasn't "normal".
I took the head apart - couldn't find my tool so I used the tips of an adjustable wrench - and cleaned it again with vinegar/water and also dish soap.  It was pretty scummy so I used an old toothbrush to scrub the screen inside and out.
Put it back together and it's much better now.

Answer (score 1):

Lady Lux kitchen faucets, like other faucets contain a screen, that over a period of time will fill with mineral deposits and debris that will clog the screen and restrict water flow. To gain access to and clean the Lady Lux faucet screen, perform steps 1 through 5 following:

1. Extend the spray head and metal hose from the faucet body and manually unfasten the spray head from the metal hose. Temporarily secure the metal hose in place to  prevent it from slipping back into the faucet body.
2. With the spray head facing up, place the hex head cutout of the plastic knob installation tool supplied with the faucet, over the rubberized molded hex nut of the spray head and unfasten the spray face from the spray head. If the installation tool is not available, use a suitable open end or crescent wrench to unfasten the molded rubberized spray face hex nut. Exercise care not to gouge the the rubberized molded hex nut.
3. Remove the screen and o-ring and clean with a mixture of white vinegar and water.
4. Once cleaning is completed, install the screen and o-ring in place and tighten the molded rubberized hex nut to fasten the the spray face to the spray head. Use care not to gouge the rubberized hex nut.
5. Tighten the assembled spray head to the metal hose and turn faucet on to verify proper water flow.